# Cupertino/Pantheon task bar (panel) does not show 22.04

Tags: ubuntu-mate, taskbar, tweak

I love the mac styled Ubuntu Mate taskbar (or panel as they call it in MATE).
However, it has been (all since Ubuntu 18.04) a pain in the neck how lazy it shows up, when I give it a mouse trigger - by navigating to where it is supposed to pop up.
Now that my Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly crashed forcing me to upgrade 22.04 (spent 8+ hours trying to fix my old good 20.04) it is getting even unacceptable and this great feature becomes practically useless.
Is there anything I could try to have it really intelligently pop up ?
I feel like all those options in the Mate-Tweak utility do NOT have any real effect to the task-bar behavior - especially when it comes to hiding/popping up.
Even when I right-click the panel (gotta aim precisely on black between some task icons), and choose 'Preferences' - it gives me additional options to tweak the behavior. But it leaves me breathless and helpless how little utility this tool has either.

[image]

I also do not see any difference between Cupertino & Pantheon

**Edit:** The install is fresh, settings are default (delay to mouse hover = 0). PC is very powerful and HW acceleration - I do not believe it is an issue. It could be something with mouse event mess in the default settings. Can we tune it ?

Any help is welcome.
P.S. I really hate the idea to install & get used to something that still works - like Linux Mint...

Comment: Can't help you with your problem but have a hint for you: you can open the panel preferences easily when you hold the `Ctrl`-key pressed and right-click the panel, no need to find the tiny free space between two icons to open the context menu.

Comment: @mook765  Good one - thank you ! ;)